# Show that it is an algebraic extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, extension-field

I want to check that $F(a,b)/F(1/ab,a+b)$ is an algebraic extension, where $a,b$ are nonzero elements of $E$, where $E/F$ is field extension.

I don't mean full solution, but I want some hint.. I think this problem much time, but there aren't any good ideas :( But if you give solution, it's good, too!

If you suggest some hint, or idea, then I will appreciate very much!

Comment: Hint: $(x-a)(x-b) = x^2 - (a+b) + ab$.

Answer (score 1):

Removed: the hint of Richard James is better than my answer.